# Propagation velocity of circular gravity-capillary surface waves in shallow water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, dispersion

My question deals with the general dispersion relation for gravity-capillary surface waves in shallow water. I stumbled across the follwing two dispersion relations:

$w^2 = gk + k^3 \sigma/\rho$ (from "L. D. Landau and E. M. Lifshitz, Fluid Mechanics" [I changed $\alpha$ for $\sigma$])

and

$(w-Uk)^2 = (gk+k^3\sigma/\rho)\tanh(kh)$ (from a paper citing the book above).

I couldn't find this exact form of the dispersion relation in the fluid mechanics book I mentioned and would therefore like to know what $U$ is and where the tanh-term comes from. Furthermore, I wanted to ask whether the second dispersion relation is in its "most general" form and also holds for shallow water with $h\approx 0.1$mm.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is the dispersion relation for plane or one dimensional surface waves in shallow water; $h$ is the depth. If the surface tension term is negligible (low-$k$ regime) it also applies to circular waves (two-dimensional) on water. I'm not sure if the surface tension term takes the same form in this case.

The second result is the dispersion relation for plane waves on shallow water with flow speed $U$, but now it definitely does not apply in the two-dimensional case. So whether either of these results apply to the case you are interested in (since the title says circular waves) is unclear to me. Hunting formulae and then asking Stack exchange what they apply to is not a good way to study Physics!